# How to access images within application folder

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to display some images in webpage which are stored inside application folder.

[image: Directory structure]

Due to some security issues, those images are not supposed to be accessed without logging in to the website.

I have read that image folder are to be placed in root directory, but those are accessible from the web page.

Comment: Could you show the content of the `.htaccess` file inside the application folder?

Comment: RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|robots\.txt)
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to output these images through the controller. For this:

1. Add a new route. For example: `$route['images/(:any)'] = 'main/images/$1';`.
2. Add a method to the controller (or a new controller).

For example:

```
public function images($file)
{
    // TODO: check auth OR permission OR what you need

    $image = APPPATH . '/images/' . $file;
    if (file_exists($image))
    {
        $content = file_get_contents($image);
        header("Content-Type:application/octet-stream");
        echo $content;
    }
    else
    {
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    }
}
```